# Using a single script to be used in multiple Jenkins jobs?

Tags: shell, jenkins

Is it possible that we would have one script that would get called twice by Jenkins passing in parameters for the different projects to build.

Here is how my builds are set up:

Build 1:

- Pulls a `git_repo 1`. Repo includes `buildscript1.sh`
- Has parameters set up. Only parameter that is different is the name of solution file. When `buildscript1.sh` is called in Jenkins, `repo1.sln` is passed in a file name to the script.

Build 2:

- Pulls a `git_repo 2`. Repo includes `buildscript2.sh`
- Has parameters set up. Only parameter that is different is the name of solution file. When `buildscript2.sh` is called in Jenkins, `repo2.sln` is passed in a file name to the script.

`buildscript1.sh` and `buildscript2.sh` are exactly the same. What I essentially want is to just manage one script file. i.e templatize the scripts, where one script is run and Jenkins automatically passes in both parameters one after the other.

Answer (score 0):

Project *Configure* → ***General*** → ***Build*** → <kbd>**Add build step   ▼**</kbd> → ***Execute shell*** → *Command*:

Build 1:

```
/path/to/your/only/buildscript.sh repo1.sln
```

Build 2:

```
/path/to/your/only/buildscript.sh repo2.sln
```

Comment: Thank You for the answer. Is there a specific way the project would need to be configured? When I try to call both repos in the same project it freaks out, and recursively starts building, calling itself 4 times every 5 seconds.

Comment: @AliShahbaz What do exactly mean by "_**call** both repos_" and how do you do that? [Note: You can update/edit your question with the link bottom-right to it.]

Comment: By that I mean, pulling both repos in one job. When you go to configure, there is an option to call git repos into the project.

Comment: @AliShahbaz "Call" is usually used for running non-local code at runtime, like functions, methods, scripts, etc., not for repositories. Your question's title reads "_a single script to be used in multiple Jenkins jobs_". Adding two repos in one job/project and its arising issues is probably worth a new question. And without config details or at least the Console Log output it's hard to tell what and why it happens.